# How to setup react.js in laravel 5.3 using laravel-elixir?

Tags: laravel, reactjs, laravel-5.3, laravel-elixir

I'm trying to installation react.js using npm as per guid in laravel front-end setup environment but not success for setup laravel.

Here's facing issue as below error:

```
events.js:141
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^
Error: Parse Error: Line 9: Illegal export declaration
    at throwError (/opt/lampp/htdocs/react_laravel/node_modules/react-tools/node_modules/esprima-fb/esprima.js:2813:21)
    at throwErrorTolerant (/opt/lampp/htdocs/react_laravel/node_modules/react-tools/node_modules/esprima-fb/esprima.js:2825:24)
    at parseSourceElement (/opt/lampp/htdocs/react_laravel/node_modules/react-tools/node_modules/esprima-fb/esprima.js:6387:17)
    at parseProgramElement (/opt/lampp/htdocs/react_laravel/node_modules/react-tools/node_modules/esprima-fb/esprima.js:6446:16)
    at parseProgramElements (/opt/lampp/htdocs/react_laravel/node_modules/react-tools/node_modules/esprima-fb/esprima.js:6478:29)
    at parseProgram (/opt/lampp/htdocs/react_laravel/node_modules/react-tools/node_modules/esprima-fb/esprima.js:6491:16)
    at Object.parse (/opt/lampp/htdocs/react_laravel/node_modules/react-tools/node_modules/esprima-fb/esprima.js:7653:23)
    at getAstForSource (/opt/lampp/htdocs/react_laravel/node_modules/react-tools/node_modules/jstransform/src/jstransform.js:251:21)
    at transform (/opt/lampp/htdocs/react_laravel/node_modules/react-tools/node_modules/jstransform/src/jstransform.js:274:11)
    at innerTransform (/opt/lampp/htdocs/react_laravel/node_modules/react-tools/main.js:94:10)
```

Comment: What commands are you using?

Comment: Need to execute simple example using laravel-elixir [Simple Example](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/reactjs/reactjs_jsx.htm),

Comment: @prgrm `npm install react --save
npm install react-dom --save
npm install babel-core
npm install babel-loader
npm install babel-preset-react
npm install babel-preset-es2015
npm install --global gulp-cli
sudo npm install --global gulp-cli
sudo apt-get install build-essential
sudo apt-get install libicu-dev
npm install laravel-react --save-dev`